# 19.10 won't boot from USB but all previous versions work fine

Tags: boot, usb, 19.10

Generic Gigabyte EP45 motherboard system, boots 19.04 18.10 18.04 etc. just fine from USB, won't boot 19.10.  Tried with multibootusb instead of straight dd / buffer, still won't work.  Just hangs somewhere in the loading process.

I saw someone claim this question is answered by "just install 19.04 and upgrade" - ffs, are you serious?

Comment: PS this does not have any uefi or whatever, it is old school, and there has only ever been Linux on the machine, never windows, just xubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit your question and add the new information you have in comments in the the question. Have you checked the downloaded ISO file for corruption? See [How to verify Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)